# Database not browsable during COPY on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, copy, psql

When using `COPY` to restore a `CSV` file, phppgadmin shows that the real database size(4GB) but when I choose to browse the table it shows `Estimated row count` to 0. I did a `VACUUM ANALYZE`. simple `SELECT` queries returns 0 rows, but the database size is 4GB. Also:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM tbl_data
```

return 0. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this question on PostgreSQL. They told:

> `COPY` runs inside a transaction, so it is not visible to outside.

Answer (score 2):

Because the estimated row count is just that -- an estimate.  IIRC, the stats aren't updated until after the copy, and perhaps not after that (you might have to do a `VACUUM ANALYZE` first).